# Get all posts (of any post type) an attachment is used in

Tags: attachments, media, media-library

It's not easy to count the amount of posts an image is attached to - WordPress simply doesn't keep track of that. It just keeps track of the post an attachment was originally uploaded to (not necessarily even using it there).

[image]

## Plugin

To get you started as quick as possible, here's the plugin code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Media Count
 * Description: Adds a column to the media admin list table to show the count of posts
 */

add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', function( $cols, $detached )
{
    $cols['count'] = 'Count';
    $cols['size']  = 'Size';
    return $cols;
}, 10, 2 );

add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', function( $col, $id )
{
    switch ( $col )
    {
        case 'size' :
            $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
            // Image
            isset( $meta['width'] )
                AND print "{$meta['width']} &times; {$meta['height']}";
            // Audio
            isset( $meta['bitrate'] )
                AND print "{$meta['length_formatted']} min";
            break;
        case 'count' :
            $att  = get_post_custom( $id );
            $file = $att['_wp_attached_file'][0];
            // Do not take full path as different image sizes could
            // have different month, year folders due to theme and image size changes
            $file  = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            // @TODO Fill in the blanks
            break;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

## Question:

How to count the amount of posts an attachment is used in - the most efficient way.

## Final Plugin

The full plugin can be **[downloaded as Gist here](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/086d754ac492f49b78b8)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Second pass**. Known issues:

- Needs caching (and the cache needs to be tidied up where possible)
- Post types are hard-coded
- Which post statuses are we interested in?

Here's the function:

```
/**
 * Given an attachment ID, searches for any post with that attachment used
 * as a featured image, or if it is present in the content of the post.
 * (Note above known issues).
*/
function get_image_count( $id ){
    global $wpdb;

    $att  = get_post_custom( $id );
    $file = $att['_wp_attached_file'][0];
    //Do not take full path as different image sizes could
    // have different month, year folders due to theme and image size changes
    $file = sprintf( "%s.%s",
        pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ),
        pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION )
    );

    $sql = "SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID 
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} 
        ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) 
        WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'event') 
        AND (({$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')) 
        AND ( ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
            AND CAST({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AS CHAR) = '%d') 
            OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE %s )
        ) 
        GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID";

    $prepared_sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $id, "%src=\"%".$wpdb->esc_like( $file )."\"%" );

    $post_ids  = $wpdb->get_results( $prepared_sql );

    $count = count( $post_ids );

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: One thing we mentioned in chat was that the LIKE statement can be improved to avoid some silly edge cases. E.g. `<img src="not-what-you-want.png"> [anything] what-you-want.png"`

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition, as an improvement to account for different image sizes, I would do:

```
$file_name      = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
$file_extension = '.' . pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
```

Instead having a combined value for `$file`.

And change the SQL preparation to:

```
$prepared_sql =
    $wpdb->prepare(
        $sql,
        $id,
        "%src=\"%"
            . like_escape( $file_name )
            . "%"
            . like_escape( $file_extension )
            . "\"%"
    );
```

---

As second addition an example that makes use of MySQL's `REGEXP`/`RLIKE` functionality, it additionally does get images just linked in an `a` tag, besides that, this is capable - contrary to the first addition, which only gets the full, uploaded size - of getting the image independent from the image size - where, for example, »the-image.jpg« would be full size and »the-image-150x150.jpg« a generated size - used:

```
$file_name      = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
// beware different syntax
$file_extension = '[[...]]'.pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

$sql = "SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID 
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} 
    ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) 
    WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'event') 
    AND (({$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')) 
    AND ( ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
        AND CAST({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AS CHAR) = '%d') 
        OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_content REGEXP %s )
    ) 
    GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID";

$exp =
    '([[.<.]])' // tag start
        . '(img|a)' // define tag types
        . '.*' // other attributes void
        . '(src|href)' // define anchor(s) attribute
        . '=([[.".]]|[[.\'.]])' // quotes
        . '.*' // path/URL void
        . $file_name
        . '.*' // image size void
        . $file_extension
        . '([[.".]]|[[.\'.]])' // quotes
        . '.*' // other attributes void
        . '([[.>.]])' // tag end
    ;

$prepared_sql =
    $wpdb->prepare(
        $sql,
        $id,
        $exp
    );

$post_ids  = $wpdb->get_results( $prepared_sql );
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! The only thing we still haven't solved is that the anchor `src` might differ from the actual HTML in the tag.

Comment: My pleasure. Not quite sure if I follow what you said, the `img` tag is a non-closing tag. So, what tag are we talking about? @kaiser

Comment: A caption of any kind as [Stephen described](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154324/get-all-posts-of-any-post-type-an-attachment-is-used-in/154347?noredirect=1#comment222412_154325).

Comment: Ok, I see, might be doable, but not for me...on the fly at least. Normally I would say regular expression, but MySQL doesn't support - all those fun and handy - capturing groups to do so. On the other hand MySQL `REGEXP` could be used to get images in other tags, like those only linked in an `a` tag - added a example to the answer. @kaiser

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Have I ran the code code before posting, yes, works on first sight like expected. Did I thoroughly test it trough, hell no! But its pretty much just an `REGEXP` replacement for the `LIKE`, with the addition of the `a` tag `href` capability, so I'm not really expecting any problems. Another note, `REGEXP` is performance wise a bit more expensive then `LIKE` and a bit slower in the process, but its really only getting relevant for huge(r) amounts of data and even then, I think, its absolutely fine and not a real problem anyway, if the purpose justifies it. @kaiser

Comment: Maybe you somehow should [edit] the answer to include the fact that this will care about all different image sizes when they append the size to the file name.

Comment: Getting following error when I try to run the above query, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

WordPress database error: Got error 'POSIX collating elements are not supported at offset 2' from regexp]